# How to fix "Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "ABC" does not exist"?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to fetch data from an existing postgres db which has a couple of tables in it. While the connection to the database is carried out successfully, I cannot seem to carry out any test queries for example

```
Model.findAll().then(table =>{ console.log(table)}
```

I have tried appending the Schema Name to the model definition like

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Schema.ABC', { ....}}
```

which throws the same error as the title suggests

I have also tried appending the Schema name to the query but it throws a syntax error and the code doesn't execute

```
Model.findAll().then('Schema.ABC' => { console.log(Schema.ABC)}
```

If the table does need to have Schema name appended to it, then I would also like to know how to achieve it.

Below is a fragment of my code

```
const Model = sequelize.define('ABC',{
    CompanyName: Sequelize.STRING,
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE
},
{
    // tableName: `"Schema"."ABC"`,
    freezeTableName: true
});

...
Model.removeAttribute('id');

Model.findAll().then(ABC => {
    console.log(ABC)
})
```

Comment: What's your table name?

Comment: Table name is ABC here.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your schema like this, leaving the `tableName` property uncommented:

```
const ABC = sequelize.define('ABC',{
    CompanyName: Sequelize.STRING,
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'ABC',
  });
```

And use this, inside of an asynchronous function:

```
async function findAllABC() {
  await ABC.findAll().then((result) => {
    console.log(`The result is: '${result}'`);
  });
}

findAllABC();
```

Comment: Using await throws me another error

    SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: You need to wrap it in an async function, normally you have a controller. I updated my answer, check it out.